# Azure Web/API App - Mapping a shared drive

Tags: azure, azure-storage, file-storage

My Azure API app uses the new Windows File storage API.

In the startup on my Azure API app I need to map to a UNC path.  The 3rd party application we integrate with needs to reference a local/UNC path for files.

In doing so I am getting a Error: ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Is it possible to map a UNC path to Azure File Store in a Web/API app?

If so - is it possible to run the app pool under an elevated account?

Or can I map this drive before using a different account somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to add a UNC path to an Azure File.

You may getting an access denied due to different user contexts between file share creation and access. Please check out the **Persist your storage account credentials for the virtual machine** section in this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/
Additionally, you could use canned user (storage account name, key) credentials to run the app pool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Ended up manually using the REST api to read/write files. Due to permission errors we couldnt get this working with out API app